# Why isn't $\sqrt{n}$ always 1?

Tags: radicals, divergent-series

My friend recently came to me with this "proof":

$ a = \sum_0^\infty (-1)^n \times 1 = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + \dots = \frac{1}{2} $

$ \sqrt{n} = n^{\frac{1}{2}} = n^{1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + \dots} = n^{(1 - 1) + (1 - 1) + \dots} = n^{(1 - 1)} \times n^{(1 - 1)} \times \dots = n^0 \times n^0 \times \dots = 1 \times 1 \times 1 \dots = 1$

What's the problem here?

I have two ideas myself: a. that $1 - 1 + 1 - \dots$ is just an idea and not something that can be adopted to "usual" calculations (if so, how are these things called?). Or b., the error lies in finally "deciding" the previously "undecided" value of $a$ by favouring a certain bracketing-order? He could have chosen $1 + (1 - 1) + (1 - 1) + \dots = 1 + (0) + (0) + \dots = 1$ instead at that point.

Or is it something completely different? Clever and funny idea though.

Comment: Why $\sum_0^{\infty}(-1)^n = 1/2$?

Comment: It starts wrong and gets worse :-).  $a\ne \frac 12$ - there is no defined value for the infinite series you give.

Comment: These sort of things can be amusing the **first** time you see them. Of course you are manipulating divergent series as though they were convergent.

Comment: FYI: $1-1+1-1+\cdots$ is called [Grandi's Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi%27s_series), a classic example of the problematic nature of divergent series. Saying that its sum is $1/2$ is ... inappropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could use your argument, then:

$$\frac{1}{2}=1+(-1)+1+(-1)+\cdots = (1-1)+(1-1)+\cdots =0$$

So you hardly need to go to square roots to find a contradiction.

You are dealing with a different sort of "summation" here than a standard summation. It does not allow you to group terms. In the more general sense, it is a [Ramanujan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation), and we should, to be precise, write $(\mathfrak R)$ to indicate this:

$$1+(-1)+1+(-1)+\cdots = \frac{1}{2}\,(\mathfrak R)$$

(There are also some alternative summations that would return the same value, such as Cesàro summations, but Ramanujan summations is one of the most general. When Cesàro summation exists, a Ramanujan summation exists.)

Unfortunately, Ramanujan sums are deeply technical, and a lot of popular math sites and videos nowadays seems to want to shout:

> "OMG, $1+2+3+\cdots =\frac{-1}{12}$!!!"

It's been a source of much frustration on this site because, while there is some real math being loosely described in the above:

1. It is an abuse of standard notation, and
2. It misleads students just learning infinite sums.

Ramanujan (and other non-standard sums) can be mysterious. For example, you can't simply remove zeros. For example:

$$1+0+(-1)+1+0+(-1)+\cdots =\frac{2}{3}\,(\mathfrak R)$$

But all we've done is add zeros between each $1,-1$ pair.

We've also seen that you can't just group terms together. (Technically, you also can't do this in standard infinite sums, either, but if a sum is already know to converge, we can group the terms like this and it still converges to the same number.)

The sorts of manipulations you can do with the terms, when computing a Ramanujan sum, are very different from (and more limited than) the sorts of manipulations you can do with standard infinite series.

Ramanujan sums can be fascinating - especially when they seem to be useful in dealing with facts from physics - but you have to be very careful with them. They are not as simple as they appear.

Answer (score 3):

Right off the bat, the statement that the infinite series $1-1+1-1+...$ is equal to $1\over 2$ is nonsense. There are ways in which we can assign values to certain divergent series, including the one above, but in no sense can we actually treat the two as *equal*.

This is discussed in the particular case above [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_of_Grandi%27s_series); more generally, look up "Cesaro summation" and "Abel summation" to get started. What these "summation" methods do is assign individual numbers to certain "formal series" *(series where I'm not paying attention to whether they converge or not; really, I'm just talking about the sequences of partial sums)* like $1-1+1-1+...$ above in ways which satisfy certain nice properties. Sometimes notation is horribly abused, and people write something like $$"1-1+1-1+...={1\over 2},"$$ or perhaps more internet-famously these days $$"1+2+3+4+5+...=-{1\over 12}."$$ But it must be understood that **these are not actual equalities in any sense**.

---

I think the following example might help explain the difference between *producing equalities* and *assigning numbers* with regard to summing divergent series.

There are lots of ways to assign numbers to formal series. Some of these include:

- $\alpha$: To the formal series $s_1+s_2+s_3+...$, assign it $s_3$.
- $\beta$: To the formal series $s_1+s_2+s_3+...$, assign it its sum if it converges and otherwise assign it $17$.

And so on. Now the above are silly, and they have **bad properties**:

- If we replace $s_1+s_2+s_3+...$ with $0+s_1+s_2+s_3+...$, $\alpha$ changes from $s_3$ to $s_2$, even though these two formal series really "should" have equal value.
- If we consider the three formal series $$s=s_1+s_2+s_3+...,\quad t=t_1+t_2+t_3+..., \quad s+t=s_1+t_1, s_2+t_2, s_3+t_3, ...$$ $\beta$ assigns all three the value "$17$," even though the third "should" be assigned the sum of the first two.

Methods like Cesaro summation do **not** yield equalities; rather, they are again methods of assigning numbers to formal series. The difference between them and the pointless stuff above is that they **do** have various nice properties, but they are the same "type" of thing. While of mathematical value, you can't use them in the same way that you use actual sums of series.

Comment: It's not exactly "nonsense," exactly, it is just terribly terribly misleading. It might better be written: $$1+(-1)+1+(-1)+\cdots = \frac{1}{2}\left(\mathfrak R\right)$$ where $\mathfrak R$ means the Ramanujan sum.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I disagree - the claim is that the two expressions really are equal, not that there is some meaningful mathematical connection between them, and this is nonsense. (It is I suppose *less* nonsense than other statements, but it's still nonsense.)

Comment: Well, is $1+1/2+1/4+\cdots = 2$? There are a lot of properties of Cesaro summability that are "nice." It depends on what we mean by the left hand side, really. What is remarkable about various other "good" definitions of infinite sums is that (1) They agree with the standard limit when that converges, (2) they are well defined (don't achieve multiple values) (3) they are linear, so $\sum(\alpha a_i+\beta b_i)=\alpha \sum a_i+\beta\sum b_i,$ when $\sum a_i$ and $\sum b_i$ exist.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't really understand what you're getting at. Of course $1+{1\over 2}+{1\over 4}+...=2$. And of course $1-1+1-1+...\not={1\over 2}$. So what? The fact that e.g. Cesaro summation gives the correct result for convergent series doesn't mean that the statement "$1-1+1-1+...={1\over 2}$" isn't nonsense. Of course there is a way to interpret it so that it is true, but that interpretation involves changing how we define basic pieces of notation, so that's sort of missing the point.

Comment: That assumes a certain definition of what it means for $a_1+a_2+\cdots + = b,$ is all I'm saying, and that various other definitions are merely different definitions.

Comment: But my objection is really to the word "nonsense." It doesn't help the OP at all. You can, in fact, give that value to the sum, and, in some sense, $\frac{1}{2}$ is the only value you can give to the sum. You can think perhaps of the Cesaro sum, or the Ramanujan sum, as "principal values of the sum." What is remarkable is that we can use a variety of different definitions of this principal value, and they tend to all agree in cases where defined. When the Cesaro sum exists, so does the Ramanujan sum, and they are equal.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews "That assumes a certain definition of what it means for $a_1+a_2+⋯=b$." Yes, it does, since there *is* a standard definition. I think calling the bald statement "$1-1+1-1+...={1\over 2}$" (without any context at all) nonsense **is** helpful to the OP, or at least might be; I think it's important that they understand that the issue is really that what they mean by that statement is completely false. I don't mean to disparage broader summation methods, and I am of course aware of the mathematical points you make. You may of course downvote if you wish, but I stand by my statement.

Comment: Except the error the OP makes is still an error in the obvious context in which they are making it, so going straight to "nonsense" doesn't really help them understand their error.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't understand what you mean. Their main error as I see it is thinking that $1-1+1-1+...$ *is* genuinely $1\over 2$. In my opinion, they need to first understand why that's not true at all before they learn how it can be interpreted to *be* true. I think we're going around in circles at this point, so I'm going to bow out.

Comment: Nope, that isn't the main error. The main error is that there is a context in which that sum equals $1/2$, but you can't manipulate the sum that way. The square root is irrelevant. If $1+(-1)+1+(-1)+\cdots = \frac{1}{2}$ in some definition, then in that definition of the sum, if it is consistent, you cannot group terms - you cannot write: $1+(-1)+1+(-1)+\cdots = (1-1)+(1-1)+\cdots,$ or you'd get $\frac12=0,$ and thus our summation method must not be well-defined. Basically, with Cesaro sums, we can't willy-nilly group terms, and the same with Ramanujan sums.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is
$$
u_n=\left(-1\right)^n 
$$
does not tend to $0$ hence the series does not exist. The value you gave it is not rigorous and has no sense at all, first what's behind $" + \ ..."$ ?